# How to use the TabView in MAUI . In Xamarin forms we can use it in the Xamarin toolkit itself

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, maui, tabview

> This is how i used to access the TabView on Xamarin Forms where it can have the ability to swap between several tabs.

```
<Grid>
    <xct:TabView
        TabStripPlacement="Top"
        TabStripBackgroundColor="{StaticResource Background}"
        TabStripHeight="60"
        TabIndicatorHeight="6"
        TabIndicatorColor="White"
        IsClippedToBounds="False"
        TabContentBackgroundColor="White">

        <xct:TabViewItem
            TabWidth="240"
            Text="Search Order"
            FontFamily="Roboto"
            FontFamilySelected="RobotoBold"
            TextColor="{StaticResource GrayWhite}"
            ControlTemplate="{StaticResource TabItemTemplate}"
            FontAttributesSelected="Bold"
            TextColorSelected="{StaticResource GrayWhite}"
            FontSizeSelected="{markupExtensions:OnScreenSize DefaultSize='20', Low='13', Medium='14', High='16', XHigh='18', XXHigh='20', XXXHigh='22'}"
            FontSize="{markupExtensions:OnScreenSize DefaultSize='20', Low='13', Medium='14', High='16', XHigh='18', XXHigh='20', XXXHigh='22'}">
            <Grid 
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Background}"
                ColumnDefinitions="*">
                <innerviews:SearchOrderView
                    x:Name="searchOrderView"
                    Grid.Column="0">
                </innerviews:SearchOrderView>
            </Grid>
        </xct:TabViewItem>

        <xct:TabViewItem
            TabWidth="240"
            Text="Scan Order"
            FontFamily="Roboto"
            FontFamilySelected="RobotoBold"
            TextColor="{StaticResource GrayWhite}"
            ControlTemplate="{StaticResource TabItemTemplate}"
            FontAttributesSelected="Bold"
            TextColorSelected="{StaticResource GrayWhite}"
            FontSizeSelected="{markupExtensions:OnScreenSize DefaultSize='20', Low='13', Medium='14', High='16', XHigh='18', XXHigh='20', XXXHigh='22'}"
            FontSize="{markupExtensions:OnScreenSize DefaultSize='20', Low='13', Medium='14', High='16', XHigh='18', XXHigh='20', XXXHigh='22'}">
            <Grid 
                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Background}"
                ColumnDefinitions="25*, 50*, 25*"
                RowDefinitions="15*, 70*, 15*">
                <innerviews:ScanOrderView 
                    x:Name="scanOrderView"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    >
                </innerviews:ScanOrderView>
            </Grid>
        </xct:TabViewItem>

    </xct:TabView>
</Grid>
```

> But in MAUI that feature in not available. I have Gone through some research and found out Uranium Nuget package which gives some features of the tabview but not as same as xamarin forms tabview .

```
<Grid>
    <material:TabView
        TabPlacement="Top"
        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Background}"
        Height="60"
        IsClippedToBounds="False">
        <material:TabItem      
            Title="Search Order"                 
            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TabItemTemplate}" >
            <Grid 
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Background}"
                ColumnDefinitions="*">
                <innerviews:SearchOrderView
                    x:Name="searchOrderView"
                    Grid.Column="0">
                </innerviews:SearchOrderView>
            </Grid>
        </material:TabItem>

        <material:TabItem 
            Title="Scan Order"
            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TabItemTemplate}">
            <Grid 
                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Background}"
                ColumnDefinitions="25*, 50*, 25*"
                RowDefinitions="15*, 70*, 15*">
                <innerviews:ScanOrderView 
                    x:Name="scanOrderView"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    >
                </innerviews:ScanOrderView>
            </Grid>
        </material:TabItem>

    </material:TabView>
</Grid>
```

> Can I know whether there is a different way to implement it.

`

Comment: please read [ask] before posting

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no TabView control in Maui, you can use Tabs and TabbedPage in Shell to achieve the same effect.

Use Tabs like this:

```
<Shell
    x:Class="ShellTabBarSample.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ShellTabBarSample"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">
    <TabBar>
        <Tab Title="One">
            <ShellContent
                Title="One"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
                Route="OnePage" />
        </Tab>

        <Tab Title="Two">
            <ShellContent
                Title="Two"    
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"    
                Route="TwoPage" />    
        </Tab>

        <Tab Title="Three">    
            <ShellContent    
                Title="Three"  
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"    
                Route="ThreePage" />    
        </Tab>

        <Tab Title="Four">    
            <ShellContent    
                Title="Four"   
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"    
                Route="FourPage" />    
        </Tab>    
    </TabBar>    
</Shell>
```

Use TabbedPage like this:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabbedPageSample"
            x:Class="TabbedPageWithNavigationPage.MainPage">
    <local:OnePage />
    <local:TwoPage />
    <local:ThreePage />
</TabbedPage>
```

For specific usage, you can refer to the official documentation:

[.NET MAUI Shell tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/tabs?view=net-maui-7.0)

[TabbedPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/tabbedpage?view=net-maui-7.0)

Comment: Did this solve your problem?

Comment: still working on that .Will see

Comment: Ok, waiting for your updates.

Comment: using the tab page in the shell makes the tab works but the same look and feel cannot be taken. And also am using the tabView in a content page, Therefore I have used a Nuget Package called UraniumUi.