# Is there a library or a way to code TabView in .NET MAUI?

Tags: .net, xamarin, tabs, maui

I started developing an app using Xamarin.Forms and am transitioning to .NET MAUI. I used `TabView` in Xamarin Community Toolkit a lot, and when I transitioned to .NET MAUI, I realized that is no longer available. I used `TabBar` in `AppShell` and it looks like the tabs I wanted but can't swipe in between like `TabView`. This is the code I have implementing `TabBar` in `AppShell`.

```
<TabBar Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor="White" Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor="Gray" Shell.TabBarTitleColor="#ffca73">
        <Tab Icon="home.svg" >
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" Route="MainPage" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Icon="plus.svg">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SecondPage}" Route="SecondPage" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Icon="profile.svg">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ThirdPage}" Route="ThirdPage" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
```

It works well but in order to swipe left and right to different tabs, should I use swipe gesture recognizer to do it? Or now is there a library that takes care of this? I saw this question is Stack Overflow which is the question which is very similar but it only showed the tabs and didn't work with swiping tabs.

[How to use the TabView in MAUI . In Xamarin forms we can use it in the Xamarin toolkit itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75463549/how-to-use-the-tabview-in-maui-in-xamarin-forms-we-can-use-it-in-the-xamarin-t)

Moreover, I'm not sure if I should ask this in a different question but `TabBar` expects me to put both icon and a text in each tab so if I only put an icon, there is an awkward empty space underneath the icon which is supposed to be the text area and I don't know how to get rid of that either.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/platform-specifics/tabbedpage-page-swiping

Comment: @Jason is there a way to do the same thing but in iOS? I am building cross-platform so is there a way to replace `android:TabbedPage.IsSwipePagingEnabled="true"` to something that works for both platform?

Comment: swiping to navigate tabs is a basic Android behavior, but not a standard on iOS

Comment: @Jason The link you posted is for TabbedPage,  not for Shell Tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add the swipe gesture recognizer to the Page's Root view. Such as:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp3.MainPage">
            <VerticalStackLayout>
              <VerticalStackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Left" Swiped="SwipeGestureRecognizer_SwipedLeft"/>
                <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Right" Swiped="SwipeGestureRecognizer_SwipedRight"/>
              </VerticalStackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

           </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And in the code behind:

```
private void SwipeGestureRecognizer_SwipedLeft(object sender, SwipedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void SwipeGestureRecognizer_SwipedRight(object sender, SwipedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```